# Always show scrollbar - Flutter

Tags: text, layout, dart, flutter

I have a long text and I need to show the scrollbar by default when the user enters my page.

Currently, the bars not shown until the user click over the text and this, not good behavior because the user could leave the page without notice that there is some unread text.

My code:

````
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/logo.png",
                height: 200.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Scrollbar(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Text("Long Text Here ...",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Continue"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        MaterialPageRoute route = MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage());
                        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Close"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      exit(0);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Comment: I think Scrollbar does not have that feature,but I opened a issue about that topic : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28836

Comment: Here's an implementation of it that you can use: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/beb74749bf2e743a6da294b37a7dcf8d

Comment: @mirkancal I get "a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand" when using this custom widget. Even if I wrap it with Expanded and/or SizedBox.

Answer (score 59):

**Updated Answer April 2023**

As of v2.9.0-1.0.pre, `isAlwaysShown` is deprecated and you should use `thumbVisibility` instead. Check [jayjw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7471516/jayjw)'s more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71357052/9777674

---

**Original Answer June 2020**

As of Flutter version 1.17, on `Scrollbar` you can set `isAlwaysShown` to `true`, but you must set the same `controller` for your `Scrollbar` and your `SingleChildScrollView` (and that applies to any other scrollable Widget as well).

Have in mind that, for the `Scrollbar` to be visible, there must be enough items to scroll. If there are not, the `Scrollbar` won't be shown.

Full working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // ...
              Expanded(
                child: Scrollbar(
                  controller: _scrollController, // <---- Here, the controller
                  isAlwaysShown: true, // <---- Required
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _scrollController, // <---- Same as the Scrollbar controller
                    child: Text(
                      "Long Text Here ...",
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.2),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the scrollbar does not display until I start to move it.  Is there a way for the scrollbar to always show

Comment: Check if you've defined the same controller for your Scrollbar and your scrollable Widget, and if you've set the `isAlwaysShown` to `true` in your Scrollbar

Comment: that worked, when I added the controller to both the scrollbar and the SingleChildScrollView the scrollbars became visible

Comment: @joaomarcos96 any idea why it would take me to scroll for the scrollbar to show up the first time, and then it stays up forever?  I did put the controller in both spots, but the keyboard appearing (for a dialog using a singleChildScrollview) is what triggered the need for a scroll bar.  Maybe that's related?

Comment: @Eradicatore, there may be not enough items. Try adding a lot of items to your list and see if it shows the scrollbar

Comment: @joaomarcos96 the more I think about it I think it's related to my dialog not being a full stateful widget.  Changes like this don't show up unless I pop and re-enter the dialog.  I wish there was a simple way to do dialog updates.  :(. Thanks again for sharing this method, it REALLY helped me in all the other places in my app!  love it

Comment: @Eradicatore if you use ScrollController, I suggest you turn your StatelessWidget into a StatefulWidget.

Comment: For me it would show, but I couldn't grab it, even with controller assigned. Setting `interactive: true,` on the ScrollBar fixed that.

Comment: `isAlwaysShown` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use `thumbVisibility` instead. This feature was deprecated after v2.9.0-1.0.pre.

Answer (score 20):

As of v2.9.0-1.0, `thumbVisiblity` is the proper field to set.

Note you can set this globally for your app (or a certain subtree) using [ScrollbarTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScrollbarTheme-class.html):

```
    return MaterialApp(
    ...
      theme: ThemeData(
        ...
        scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
          thumbVisibility: MaterialStateProperty.all<bool>(true),
        )
      )
    )
```

It's good to prefer themes for styling like this, so avoid doing more than once.

**You'll still need to add a Scrollbar and Controller** as described in other answers though.

Comment: I don't have a Scrollbar Controller yet your code works for me

Comment: ScrollbarTheme method works.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

Use [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar) package. It provides a dragable scrollbar with option to make the scrollbar always visible. For example, you can use the following code

```
 DraggableScrollbar.arrows(
  alwaysVisibleScrollThumb: true, //use this to make scroll thumb always visible
  labelTextBuilder: (double offset) => Text("${offset ~/ 100}"),
  controller: myScrollController,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: myScrollController,
    itemCount: 1000,
    itemExtent: 100.0,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          color: Colors.purple[index % 9 * 100],
          child: Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: do you have any solution for not use plug in?
why they didn't add 1 parameter like isScrollbarAlwaysVisible.

Comment: There are open issues and pull requests regarding this on the flutter repo, but they don't have the, implementation yet. If you don't wanna use plugin, check out this gits, this creates a custom scrollview widget with always visible scroll bar as well allows to customize the scrollbar
https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/beb74749bf2e743a6da294b37a7dcf8d

Comment: isScrollbarAlwaysVisible does not exist in the new versions of flutter

Answer (score 3):

'isAlwaysShown' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use thumbVisibility instead.

Example:

```
Scrollbar(
   controller: ScrollController(),
    thumbVisibility: true,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
```

Answer (score 1):

thumbVisibility make true for show always scroll bar for list in scrollbar widget

```
Scrollbar(thumbVisibility: true,)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add to SingleChildScrollView or ListView.

```
physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```